# RuntimeError: deleteUI: Object 'Animation_Copy_Tool' not found

Tags: python, user-interface, runtime-error, maya

Getting this error when pressing the "Close Window" button in my UI.  This button should delete the UI window but isn't. Full traceback:

Error: deleteUI: Object 'Animation_Copy_Tool' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 36, in closeBtnCmd
RuntimeError: deleteUI: Object 'Animation_Copy_Tool' not found. #

```
# Animation Copy Tool
# Bakari Holmes 5/7/2015
# This is designed to copy and existing animation
# from one rig to another and make the process easier
# with a simple UI

import maya.cmds as mc
import functools
import maya.mel as mm
import pprint

class AnimCopyWindow(object):
    #@classmethod
    def showUI(cls):
        win = cls()
        win.create()
        return win
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = "Animation Copy Tool"
        self.title = "Animation Copier"
        self.size = (546,350)

    def pasteTheseKeys(self, *args):
        self.offsetVal = mc.intFieldGrp(self.int_offset, q=True, value1=True)
        self.selObj_pasteKeys = mc.ls(sl=True)

        for objectQuant in self.selObj_pasteKeys:
            print objectQuant
            self.ct = mc.currentTime(query = True)
            self.t = self.ct + self.offsetVal
            mc.currentTime(self.t)
           # mc.selectKey(selObj_pasteKeys[objectQuant])
            mc.pasteKey(time=(self.t,self.t), f=(1.0,1.0), option="merge", copies=1, to=0, fo=0, vo=0)

    def closeBtnCmd(self,*args):
        mc.deleteUI(self.window,window=True)

    def create(self):
        # check to see if window exists already
        if mc.window(self.window,exists=True): 
            mc.deleteUI(self.window,window=True)

        self.window = mc.window(self.window, title=self.title,widthHeight=self.size,menuBar=True)
        self.copyAnim = mc.window(title="Transfer Animation Tool", backgroundColor=[0.3,0.3,0.3],sizeable=False,resizeToFitChildren=True)
        #set the layout for UI
        mc.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        self.tx_src = mc.textFieldGrp(label="Source Object", editable=False, text=sel[0])
        self.int_offset = mc.intFieldGrp(label="Frame Offset Amount", value1=0)
        #add paste animation button
        self.btn1 = mc.button(label="PASTE ANIMATION", command=self.pasteTheseKeys, bgc=[0.1,0.1,0.5])

        #add close button window
        self.btn2 = mc.button(label="CLOSE WINDOW", command=self.closeBtnCmd, bgc=[0.2,0.2,0.2])


        mc.showWindow()

        #################################
        #####end of class definition#####
        #################################

def keys_as_dictionary(channel):
    """return a dictionay of times:values for <channel>"""
    keys = mc.keyframe(channel, q=True, tc=True) or []
    values = mc.keyframe(channel, q=True, vc=True) or []
    return dict(zip(keys, values))

def channels():
    """return a dictionary of <plug>:<channel_dict> for each animated plug selected"""
    keys = mc.keyframe(sl=True, n=True, q=True)
    result = {}

    for k in keys:
        plugs = mc.listConnections(k, p=True)[0]
        result[plugs]= keys_as_dictionary(k)
    return result

#store selected object info
sel = mc.ls(selection=True)

if (len(sel) != 1):
    mm.eval("warning Must select one animated object;")

else:
    mc.copyKey()
    win = AnimCopyWindow()
    win.create()

    pprint.pprint(channels())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error almost always means your UI element is not named what you think it is:  Maya will automatically rename the items to make sure that no two siblings have the same name -- you can ask for "my_window" and get back "my_window123" .  So you need to capture the actual name that is returned from cmds.window() or whatever ui command you use and delete that. Hard coded names are never reliable